# Is there a Perl function to turn a string into a regexp to use that string as pattern?

Tags: regex, perl, string

I have trouble using Perl grep() with a string that *may* contain chars that are interpreted as regular expressions quantifiers.

I got the following error when the grep pattern is "g++" because the '+' symbols
are interpreted as quantifiers. Here is the output of for program that follows:

```
1..3
ok 1 - grep, pattern not found
ok 2 - grep, pattern found

Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE
in m/g++ <-- HERE / at escape_regexp_quantifier.pl line 8.
```

Is there a modifier I could use to indicate to grep that the quantifiers shall be ignored,
or is there a function that would escape the quantifiers ?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 

sub test_grep($)
{
    my $filter = shift;
    my @output = ("-r-xr-xr-x   3 root     bin       122260 Jan 23  2005 gcc",
                  "-r-xr-xr-x   4 root     bin       124844 Jan 23  2005 g++");
    return grep (!/$filter/, @output);
}

use Test::Simple tests => 2;

ok(test_grep("foo"), "grep, pattern not found");
ok(test_grep("gcc"), "grep, pattern found");
ok(test_grep("g++"), "grep, pattern found");
```

PS: in addition to the answer question above, I welcome any feedback on Perl usage in the above as I'm still learning.  Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The standard way is to use the `\Q` escape indicator before your variable, to tell Perl not to parse the contents as a regular expression:

```
return grep (!/\Q$filter/, @output);
```

Altering that line in your code yields:

```
1..3
ok 1 - grep, pattern not found
ok 2 - grep, pattern found
ok 3 - grep, pattern found
```

Comment: note \Q ends at \E, should probably ensure that \E in contents is escaped.

Comment: You don't need to - \E in the *interpolated* pattern causes no problems.

Answer (score 15):

I think you are looking for [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

Answer (score 8):

*in addition to the answer question above, I welcome any feedback on Perl usage in the above as I'm still learning. Thanks*

I would advice you not to use prototypes (the *($)* after test_grep). They have their uses, but not for most cases and definitely not in this one.

Comment: can you elaborate on this?  I've never seen that advice before.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-function-prototypes-bad

Answer (score 2):

> PS: in addition to the answer question
>   above, I welcome any feedback on Perl
>   usage in the above as I'm still
>   learning.

The best advice I can give for Perl coding advice in general is to install [Perl::Critic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl::Critic) and use the [perlcritic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlcritic) command on your code.  If you can't do that, you can use the [on-line perl critic tool](http://perlcritic.com/).  It will help if you have a copy of [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735/) handy, since `Perl::Critic` has already read the book and will give you references to page numbers, however even if you don't have the book around you can still find extended feedback in the [Perl::Critic documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/) sections starting with `Perl::Critic::Policy::`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using qr to create Regexp objects rather than strings in this case anyway.

```
ok(test_grep(qr/foo/), "grep, pattern not found");
ok(test_grep(qr/gcc/), "grep, pattern found");
ok(test_grep(qr/g\+\+/), "grep, pattern found");
```

Then you don't need the \Q escape.  Though you can still use it:

```
ok(test_grep(qr/\Qg++/), "grep, pattern found");
```