# Why is Perl squashing my array?

Tags: perl

Here's a short test program:

```
sub foo($;@) {
  my $sql = shift;
  my @params = @_;

  print "sql: $sql\n";
  print "params: " . join(",", @params);
}

sub bar($;@) {
  foo(@_);
}

bar("select * from blah where x = ? and y = ?",2,3);
print "\n";
```

Why is the output this:

```
sql: 3
params:
```

Rather than this?

```
sql: select * from blah where x = ? and y = ?
params: 2,3
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's because when you call `foo(@_)`, the prototype for `foo()` forces the first parameter (which is an array) to be converted into a scalar (which is the number of elements in `@_`).

See answers to my previous question asking "[Why are Perl Function Prototypes Bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-function-prototypes-bad)"?

FWIW, you can keep the prototypes in place if you change `bar` thus:

```
sub bar($;@) {
    foo(shift, @_);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You're misunderstanding Perl prototypes. Remove them and it'll work fine.

See: [Why are Perl 5's function prototypes bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-function-prototypes-bad)

Answer (score 5):

get rid of `($;@)` after your function names and it works fine.