# Basic defensive programming

Tags: defensive-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Favorite (Clever) Defensive Programming Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490420/favorite-clever-defensive-programming-best-practices)

I am always advised by some programmers to pay concentration to **easy debugging**. What is **defensive programming** and to which extend should it be considered while practicing?

And one more important question: is there any *key things* to consider while coding and what are they?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490420/favorite-clever-defensive-programming-best-practices for many examples of such practices. There are many, many questions here on defensive programming, so your question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at

- [Defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming)
- [Case Study – Defensive
  Programming](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/vba/vba-defensive_programming.htm)
- [The art of defensive programming](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/MaintainableCode.htm)

> Defensive programming is the idea that
>   the developer makes as few assumptions
>   as absolutely necessary. In addition,
>   the developer preemptively creates
>   code that anticipates not only
>   potential problems but also
>   specification changes.

Answer (score 4):

As a rule of thumb -- if you catch yourself thinking "this will always be true", write `ASSERT( condition)` in that place. That is probably the core of what defensive programming should be ;).

Answer (score 2):

If defensive programming meant only one thing , that should be **use assert extensively**.

[Here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) is a good article about when and where to use `assert`.

> There are many situations where it
>   is good to use assertions. This
>   section covers some of them:
>
> ```
> * Internal Invariants
> * Control-Flow Invariants
> * Preconditions, Postconditions, and Class Invariants
> ```

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming

Defensive programming means, that you check if a file exists and if you have the permissions to open it instead of just trying to open it and catching any eventual exceptions.
(Just an example)

Comment: That is a spectacularly bad example, as files are system-wide resources and any checks you make can be made irrelevant by the time you open the file.

Comment: I'd argue that "defensive programming" in this case would be to actually remember that IO can fail, and to catch the exception, and dealing with it in a sane manner. (as opposed to waiting for it to happen and backfitting the error handling)

Comment: @eWolf: Well, I would not call that defensive programming. Defensive programming is more about things that should be true, because provided by other part of the program, that you check nonetheless. @Daniel: Things that may fail because you call external ressource should be checked in any case defensive programming or not. Checking before accessing a file or such is not enough. You must check also result of real access, because something can happen between first check and real access that can raise error condition.

Comment: @Pete: I did not say that you could forgo the Try-Catch, neither did I say that these checks were a good idea.
@Daniel: You should always put IO, database, network or similar code in a Try-Catch, shouldn't you?