# Unintended assignment

Tags: c++

I heard some programmers use `if(1 == var)` instead of `if(var == 1)` to avoid unintended assignment. Why or in what cases does it cause unintended assignment?

Comment: Because sometimes people accidentally write `if (var = 1)`.  Personally I find (1 == var) incredibly annoying.  You shouldn't be making those mistakes after writing a few programs and on the off chance you do they are usually easy to find with a debugger.

Comment: btw it's called a Yoda condition.

Comment: Compilers should warn about that.

Comment: I saw it on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490420/favorite-clever-defensive-programming-best-practices/ , actually I don't care about this point stuff, this is my 3rd or 4th account on S.O because I always forget my password/login or something, I was just curious what the `assignment` thing was. I've been self studying for a long time and I learned that asking instead of making my own assumptions is always better, not to count how much I've learned just in S.O. You can -1 how much you want^^ it's no big deal, I'm just here for learning

Comment: Re "Personally I find (1 == var) incredibly annoying." That's far too nice. This is an absolutely ugly construct that is completely at odds  with how people think.

Comment: Alf, perhaps it might be a good idea to assume good faith?

Comment: [Asked and answered on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/74086/8)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is if you mistype the statement:

```
if (var = 1)
```

vs

```
if (1 = var)
```

In the first case, the code after the `if` is executed unconditionally (with no more than a warning from the compiler, which isn't obliged to produce a warning for you — but the good ones do; if you aren't using a good compiler, get one!).  In the second case, you get a syntax error at compile time, so the problem has to be fixed before the code can compile.

The problem isn't always as blatant:

```
if (var = 0)
```

never executes the code after the `if`, of course.  Often though, you'll have:

```
if (var = function(arg1, arg2))
```

and it won't be clear whether you intended to assign or compare.  You can make it clear to the compiler and code readers (humans) by writing:

```
if ((var = function(arg1, arg2)) != 0)
```

or

```
if (var == function(arg1, arg2))
```

I don't use the 'back-to-front' comparison technique. I dislike the inverted conditions because they almost invariably read 'wrong' to me. I'm not comparing 1 with my variable; I'm comparing my variable with 1.  So, even though logically the `==` operator is commutative, I don't think commutatively and prefer that 'riskier' way.  I have not found myself making the assignment vs equality mistake often enough for the issue to be a problem.  The compiler warns me if I do make a mistake (and I pay attention to the warning and fix the code so that there isn't a problem).

Comment: Even when my compiler didn't warn me, it still didn't take long to find. When something's always executing, it's easy to notice. It's like forgetting a break in a case label.

Comment: @chris you may not notice it when the `if` statement is not in the default code execution path.

Comment: @ouah, True, but when you test your program, you should be testing that area as well.

Comment: @Jonathan, Good point, that edit with `var = 0` happens too. Finding code that doesn't run when it should is a bit more tricky sometimes.

Comment: Well my compiler generates C2106 for `if( x = 0 )` but it doesn't if 2 vars are in question `if( y = x )`

Comment: GCC 4.7.1 gives a warning: `x.c: In function ‘main’:` and `x.c:7:5: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]`.  This is for `if (x = y)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you mistype it as

```
if (var = 1)
```

that would cause unintended(?) assignment. Decent compilers warn about that unless you include an extra set of parentheses

```
if ((var = 1))
```

to make your intention clear to the compiler.

Comment: Annoying compilers warn about that unless you include an extra set of parentheses.

Comment: Well, okay, every time I've gotten that warning so far, it was because I forgot the parentheses. But still, I'd rather the compiler warned me if some time I really didn't mean to assign.