# Call to a Member Function fill() on Null Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, runtime-error, null-pointer, laravel-controller

I've been trying to edit a record. My code will create a new record if the data is null. However, I get the following error:

> Call to a member function `fill()` on null.

I'm not sure what I did wrong; maybe I didn't declare?

**Controller**

```php
<?php

public function auctionUpdate(Request $request, MediaSite $mediaSite)
{
    $auction = $mediaSite->auction;

    DB::transaction(function() use ($request, $mediaSite, $auction){
        $auction->fill($request->only([
           'status', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'period_start_date'
        ]));

        if($auction == null)
            $auction = new Auction();

        $auction->save();
   });

   return view('admin.media-site.show', [
       'mediaSite' => $mediaSite,
       'auction' => $auction
   ]);
}
```

Comment: What is `MediaSite`? What is being passed to your function for the `$mediaSite` argument? Presumably, `$mediaSite->auction` is `null`. Should you perhaps move your `if($auction == null)
            $auction = new Auction();` up above `$auction->fill()`?

Comment: MediaSite is a model that also has link to Auction model. I want to edit the auction data through media site model

Comment: You should check for null and give an error the earliest you can. The validating code should check external output, being only in the outer parts of the code not in the inner code. **Avoid Defensive Programming, Fail Fast Instead** https://stackoverflow.com/a/490500/2739274

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if auction is null before fill()

your modified script

```
public function auctionUpdate(Request $request, MediaSite $mediaSite)
{
    $auction = $mediaSite->auction;

    DB::transaction(function() use ($request, $mediaSite, $auction){
        if($auction == null)
            $auction = new Auction();

        $auction->fill($request->only([
           'status', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'period_start_date'
        ]));

        $auction->save();
   });



   return view('admin.media-site.show', [
       'mediaSite' => $mediaSite,
       'auction' => $auction
   ]);
}
```

Comment: solved the error but edit and save doesn't work. Thanks btw.

Comment: i just realized that i can edit but i cannot save if it is blank value.

Comment: whats the exception

Comment: sorry, i don't understand the whats the exception?

Comment: remove DB transaction , then you will get the error

Comment: ok  i just did something and when i click save it doesn't show the updated data but when i left and go back to the page, the info was there. so the data is saved, it just doesn't updated on the page. Thanks btw.