# How can I parse command-line switches in Perl?

Tags: perl, parsing, command-line, arguments

In order to extend my ["grep" emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506009/scanning-multiple-files-in-perl) in Perl I have added support for a `-r` switch which enables recursive searching in sub-directories. Now the command line invocation looks something like this:

```
perl pgrep.pl -r <directory> <expression>
```

Both `-r` and the `directory` arguments are optional (directory defaults to '.'). As of now I simply check if the first argument is `-r` and if yes set the appropriate flag, and scan in the rest two arguments using the shift operation. This obviously would be a problem if `-r` were to appear at the end of the argument list or worse still - in between the directory name and the search expression.

One workaround would be to simply delete the `-r` item from the @ARGV array so that I can simply **shift**-in the remaining arguments, but I can't figure out a way to do it without getting an 'undef' in an odd position in my array. Any suggestions or different strategies that you might have used are welcome.

Comment: I would select a different answer.

Comment: Well, the accepted answer doesn't really answer the asked question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be using [`GetOpt::Long`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long). This will do everything you need as described.

Comment: Is that link more up to date or different in a significant way?

Comment: @dsm: The "perldoc?" link is better because it returns the latest version. It has been discused here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758/how-should-i-link-to-cpan-modules-in-answers

Answer (score 4):

```
use Getopt::Std;

our $opt_r; # will be set to its value if used.
getopts('r:'); # -r has an option.
```

Answer (score 1):

- Add a -d switch for your directory. My opinion is, "if a command is optional it should have a switch to enable it."
- Also I would remove the switches(and their arguments) from the array as I read them, leaving just my "expression". If there's more than 1 element in that array, someone wrote something wrong.

Comment: How would you remove the elements from the array? Use 'shift' to go through and process the arguments or something else?

Comment: since i want to be as free to move around as possible I would probably use splice. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html It can be extremely useful. my $switch = splice(@ARGV, $offset, 1);

Answer (score 0):

My chapter on "Configuration" in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242/) goes through several possibilities for command-line switch processing, from perl's `-s` to the popular modules for handling these. For your example, I'd probably start with [Getopt::Std](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Getopt-Std) and convert to [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GetOpt-Long) if I needed it later.

Good luck, :)

Answer (score 0):

One simple and lazy way, is to use `-s` switch:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s

use strict; use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

our ($dir, $expr);

say $dir if ($dir);
say $expr if ($expr);
```

### Usage

```
./script.pl -dir=. -expr='/foobar/'
```

### Output

```
.
/foobar/
```