# <0xEF,0xBB,0xBF> character showing up in files. How to remove them?

Tags: file, unicode, utf-8, utf

I am doing compressing of JavaScript files and the compressor is complaining that my files have `ï»¿` character in them.

How can I search for these characters and remove them?

Comment: That isn't `<U+FEFF>`, that is `<0xEF,0xBB,0xBF>` that is the BOM of UTF8 files, so you should change the title. How would you like to remove them? By magic fairies? By command line tool? By editing one-by-one? Notepad++ can change encoding to UTF8 without BOM. For example just googling 5 seconds of "strip BOM utf8" I've found this for Linux: http://www.ueber.net/who/mjl/projects/bomstrip/

Comment: It might help you get an answer that specifically relates to your problem if you told us what javascript tool you're using to do the compression, on what platform, and what other tools are part of your build process.

Comment: BOMs in UTF-8 are absolute crud.  You need to find the producer of that file and tell them to cut it the @#%% out.

Comment: @xanatos It [sounds like](http://www.herongyang.com/Unicode/Notepad-Byte-Order-Mark-BOM-FEFF-EFBBBF.html) `<U+FEFF>` is the _UTF-16_ BOM. Since JavaScript represents strings in a UTF-16-like way (UCS-2), I believe the UTF-8 BOM may wind up looking like a UTF-16 BOM when handling the file with JavaScript-based tools (e.g. browser dev tools / Node inspector, or in JS APIs like `String.charCodeAt()`).  That might explain what @QuintinPar was seeing.

Comment: @peterflynn: `U+FEFF` is the Unicode codepoint used for a BOM, but the BOM itself is how that codepoint is encoded (UTF-8: `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`, UTF-16LE: `0xFF 0xFE`, UTF-16BE: `0xFE 0xFF`, etc).  So the files in question are UTF-8 encoded, which the compressor is detecting when decoding them to actual Unicode codepoints.

Comment: @xanatos Regardless of what it is, this is how it manifests, and that's how people can easily find this question using search engines.

Comment: If you want just to show files containing the BOM character, use this one:
`grep $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' *.*`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
perl -pi~ -CSD -e 's/^\x{fffe}//' file1.js path/to/file2.js
```

I would assume the tool will break if you have other utf-8 in your files, but if not, perhaps this workaround can help you. (Untested ...)

**Edit**: added the `-CSD` option, as per tchrist's comment.

Comment: You need to run with the `-CSD` switch, or with the `PERL_UNICODE` envariable set to `SD`, for that to work.

Comment: Regexp works OK for removing <fffe> character at the beginning of a line, to replace all <fffe> characters in a line: 's/\x{fffe}//g'.

Comment: On Mac OSX, I had to change to: `perl -CSD -pe 's/^\x{feff}//' file.csv` , note the change from <fffe> to <feff>.

Comment: @mpettis That's not a BOM then, but a BOM with the bytes reversed. It could happen on any platform, if you convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 and get the byte-order wrong (even though the purpose of the BOM is to prevent that error!)

Comment: What about running this on an entire directory?

Comment: @blong What about it?  Ask a separate question if you can't figure it out (but it will probably be marked as a duplicate; first google hit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712188/how-do-i-run-a-perl-script-on-multiple-input-files-with-the-same-extension)

Answer (score 199):

You can easily remove them using **vim**, here are the steps:

1) In your terminal, open the file using vim:

```
vim file_name
```

2) Remove all [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) characters:

```
:set nobomb
```

3) Save the file:

```
:wq
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. It is simpler than the selected answer. Thanks

Comment: I used this great solution even though I'm normally an emacs partisan. vim ftw

Answer (score 33):

Another method to remove those characters - using **Vim**:

> vim -b fileName

Now those "hidden" characters are visible (`<feff>`) and can be removed.

Comment: I hate windows programs using many weird characters that breaks my codes. This helps A LOT at identifying weird hidden characters for many purposes.

Answer (score 26):

Thanks for the previous answers, here's a sed(1) variant just in case:

```
sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//'
```

Comment: Other sources suggest to prepend the figure 1 to the patttern, as in "sed '1 s/\xEF\xBB\xBF//'", to only match the first line. However, for me on Mac OS X, neither way works.

Comment: This worked, and was the best solution for me. Thank you, sir!

Comment: Loved this solution. Easiest to implement and still scalable... :)

Comment: @Marian A little late, but you can check [Masum's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29490814/198553) that shows why it didn't work on mac.

Comment: Add -i to sed to update the file(s) with the changes.

Answer (score 19):

**On Unix/Linux:**

```
sed 's/\xEF\xBB\xBF//' < inputfile > outputfile
```

**On MacOSX**

```
sed $'s/\xEF\xBB\xBF//' < inputfile > outputfile
```

Notice the $ after sed for mac.

**On Windows**

There is [Super Sed](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/ssed/) an enhanced version of sed. For Windows this is a standalone .exe, intended for running from the command line.

Comment: "Notice the $ after sed for mac." - Thank you sir!

Comment: The Bash "C-style" string `$'\xEF\xBB\xBF//'` is a Bash feature, not particularly a Mac or OSX feature.  WIth this contruct, Bash will parse the escape sequences into actual bytes before passing the command line to `sed`.  Depending on your `sed` variant, this may or may not work (though I'm sure it's useful for OSX users to know that it should work out of the box for them).

Comment: maybe
    sed -i 's/.../.../'

Answer (score 6):

Using *tail* might be easier:

```
tail --bytes=+4 filename > new_filename
```

Comment: This technique would fail after the producer of the file removes the BOM. Not scalable... :)

Answer (score 4):

I've used vimgrep for this

```
:vim "[\uFEFF]" *
```

also normal vim search command

```
/[\uFEFF]
```

Answer (score 3):

@tripleee's solution didn't work for me. But changing the file encoding to ASCII and again to UTF-8 did the trick :-)

Answer (score 2):

The 'file' command shows if the BOM is present:

For example: 'file myfile.xml' displays: "XML 1.0 document, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators"

dos2unix will remove the BOM.

Answer (score 2):

I'm suggest the use of "dos2unix" tool, please test to run `dos2unix ./thefile.js`.

If necessary try to use something like this for multiple files:

```
for x in $(find . -type f -exec echo {} +); do dos2unix $x ; done
```

My Regards.

Comment: I liked your answer - `bomstrip` wasn't easily available on my mac - so taking the time to give you the simple version: `find . -type f -exec dos2unix '{}' +`

Answer (score 1):

In windows you could use backported **recode** utility from [UnxUtils](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/unxutils/UnxUtils.zip?modtime=1172730504&big_mirror=0).

Answer (score 1):

In [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com) you can install the [Highlighter package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Highlighter) and then customize the regular expression in your user settings.

Here I added `\uFEFF` to the end of the `highlighter_regex` property.

```json
{
    "highlighter_enabled": true,
    "highlighter_regex": "(\t+ +)|( +\t+)|[\u2026\u2018\u2019\u201c\u201d\u2013\u2014\uFEFF]|[\t ]+$",
    "highlighter_scope_name": "invalid",
    "highlighter_max_file_size": 1048576,
    "highlighter_delay": 3000
}
```

To overwrite the default package settings place the file here:

> ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/highlighter.sublime-settings

Answer (score 0):

Save the file without code signature.