# UTF-8 i18n file

Tags: internationalization, yesod

I'm trying to add a Chinese localisation to a scaffolded Yesod site. I have a `zh.msg` message file saved as UTF-8 format using Notepad in Windows, but when I run `cabal install` in the project directory, I get this:

```
Handler\Home.hs:15:11:
    Not in scope: data constructor `MsgHello'
    Perhaps you meant `Msg<stderr>: hPutChar: invalid argument (invalid character)
```

The line in question is where I render my homepage:

```
$(widgetFile "homepage")
```

I changed both message files to be Unicode formatted instead of UTF-8, and get this message instead:

```
Foundation.hs:1:1:
    Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
    Cannot decode byte '\xff': Data.Text.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: invalid UTF-8 stream
```

So I guess UTF-8 is the way to go... somehow.

*(I'm using Notepad because I haven't set up gVim to render Unicode characters. It's apparently a bit of a feat.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I went to commit my changes I discovered the issue. The diff for my English file looked like this:

```
-Hello: Hello
+<U+FEFF>Hello: Hello
```

I guess notepad added the character in, and it was working its way into the Haskell code. I solved it using vim [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15137601/945863).