# Remove file coding mark but preserve its coding

Tags: linux, shell, utf-8

I've got a file with UTF-8 (Without BOM) coding. File is being created on Windows site and it's being transfered to Linux server through SFTP. Using `cat -e` on it, I get something like this:

```
cat -e file.txt

M-oM-;M-?test13;hbana0Kw;$
lala;LjgX$
```

Now, I know that `M-oM-;M-?` stands for UTF-8 (Without BOM). Is there a way to remove it from file but preseve its coding?

Comment: If it's not a BOM, it is actual character data which you cannot remove without altering the actual contents of the file. However, it looks to me like a BOM. What's the output of `cut -b1-3 file | od -ch`?

Comment: Hi, it's `0000000 357 273 277  \n   l   a   l  \n    
        bbef 0abf 616c 0a6c
0000010`

Comment: So it's a BOM with the bytes switched, aka a [ZERO-WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm).  (The output from `od` is in little-endian format, further confusing issues.)

Comment: Great, so I was mistaken what it is. Now, is there a way to remove it from Linux side or should I try to remove it on Windows site?

Comment: Trivially `LC_ALL=C cut -b4- file >newfile`

Comment: Yes, but it also cuts every single line in file removing first 3 characters, so i get for second line - a;LjgX instead of lala;LjgX

Comment: `sed -e '1s/^.//' file.txt`

Comment: Alternative to sed: `tail --bytes=+3 < oldfile > newfile`

Comment: @EtanReisner Still not right. It doesn't matter if I use sed on file or cut - it takes away first 3 characters from each line.

Comment: Then you missed the leading `1` on my sed command. `1s/^.//` not `s/^.//`.

Comment: @EtanReisner even worse ... I've run your `sed` command and then did `cat` on old file. For now `sed` works fine.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Did `sed` work or not? That `sed` command should only modify the first line and should print out every other line as-is. What version of `sed` are you using?

Comment: @EtanReisner Sorry, my answer was a little misleading. I meant that Your answer was right - `sed -e '1s/^.//'` works fine. I was checking wrong file for results. Can You explain to me what exactly does this command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [<U+FEFF> character showing up in files. How to remove them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297888/ufeff-character-showing-up-in-files-how-to-remove-them)

Comment: Similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381230/22653

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the BOM from the first line of a file you can use something like this `sed -e '1 s/^.//' file.txt`.

`sed` commands have two parts an address and a command. Most of the time you see `sed` used without addresses (which means apply to all lines) but you can restrict the command operation to only specific lines by using addresses.

In this case the address is `1` meaning the first line. So the replacement only applies to the first line and every line is printed (as that is the default sed behaviour).

Answer (score 5):

When transferring file from Windows to Linux, apply `dos2unix` command. This removes the BOM symbol and transforms line-edings to Unix style.

```
dos2unix file.txt
```

Comment: Worked for me, however I should mention that some really old versions of dos2unix cannot do this.