# First Line and Second Line have different positions when using 'sed' in unix

Tags: sed

The content of the file is:

```
27004700170000000000100002155000000088269044900033XXXX                                    10092019  
27004700170000000000110002555000000123823960900033XXXX                                    10092019
```

When I try this command in unix:
Show the 1st character in the first line,

```
sed -n '1p' TEST.TXT|cut -c1
```

It shows blank

but when I try to show the first character in the second line:-

```
sed -n '2p' TEST.TXT|cut -c1
```

It shows '2'.

But when I try to copy paste the file to notepad++ and transfer it to another text file, it will show both the result '2' on the first line and second line.
I don't know what part is missing.

I tried cat -A TEST.TXT and it shows the non showing character.

**M-oM-;M-?27004700170000000000100002155000000088269044900033XXXX                                    10092019  ^M$
27004700170000000000110002555000000123823960900033XXXX                                    10092019  ^M$**

There is a non showing character at the beginning.
How can I remove that character in the start of the file?

Comment: Use something like `hd TEST.TXT|head` to see what's **really** in the file.

Comment: See [Remove file coding mark but preserve its coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104700/remove-file-coding-mark-but-preserve-its-coding), in particular: they suggest: sed -e '1 s/^.//' file.txt