# Show zero-length characters

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a way to highlight zero-length characters in text files (PHP/HTML in this case). I recently had an issue with a web page not passing W3C validation due to a invalid character.

As the character in question was a `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`, it took an age to actually find it. It was purely by accident that I used `git diff` and it showed up as being `<U+FEFF>`.

It would be great if I was able to see these types of characters actually in SublimeText while I'm working on a source file.

I've turned on showing up whitespace by adding:

```
"draw_white_space": "all"
```

to my user preferences, but while that does show spaces and tabs, it doesn't show this character up.

Answer (score 1):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871144/1569064).  The answer is Sublime Text specific, but the question is not.

The linked answer suggests using the [Highlighter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Highlighter) package which, according to the docs is

> A plugin for Sublime Text 2 and 3 that highlights mixed tabs and
>   spaces and some unicode characters.

You can add `\uFEFF` to the list of regexes to highlight.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the package with the config as detailed in the answer. It already had the `\uFEFF` tacked onto the end of the regex. Sadly it doesn't seem to want to highlight that particular character, the rest of them seem to get highlighted though.