# SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier python 3.6

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as ms
import sqlite3
with sqlite3.connect('quit.db') as db:
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (username TEXT NOT NULL ,password TEXT NOT NULL);')
db.commit()
db.close()
class main:
def __init__(self, master):
    # Window
    self.master = master
    # Some Usefull variables
    self.username = StringVar()
    self.password = StringVar()
    self.n_username = StringVar()
    self.n_password = StringVar()
    # Create Widgets
    self.widgets()

# Login Function
def login(self):
    # Establish Connection
    with sqlite3.connect('quit.db') as db:
        c = db.cursor()
    # Find user If there is any take proper action
    find_user = ('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? and password = ?')
    c.execute(find_user, [(self.username.get()), (self.password.get())])
    result = c.fetchall()
    if result:
        self.logf.pack_forget()
        self.head['text'] = self.username.get() + '\n Loged In'
        self.head['pady'] = 150
    else:
        ms.showerror('Oops!', 'Username Not Found.')

def new_user(self):
    # Establish Connection
    with sqlite3.connect('quit.db') as db:
        c = db.cursor()

    # Find Existing username if any take proper action
    find_user = ('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?')
    c.execute(find_user, [(self.username.get())])
    if c.fetchall():
        ms.showerror('Error!', 'Username Taken Try a Diffrent One.')
    else:
        ms.showinfo('Success!', 'Account Created!')
        self.log()
    # Create New Account
    insert = 'INSERT INTO user(username,password) VALUES(?,?)'
    c.execute(insert, [(self.n_username.get()), (self.n_password.get())])
    db.commit()

    # Frame Packing Methords

def log(self):
    self.username.set('')
    self.password.set('')
    self.crf.pack_forget()
    self.head['text'] = 'LOGIN'
    self.logf.pack()

def cr(self):
    self.n_username.set('')
    self.n_password.set('')
    self.logf.pack_forget()
    self.head['text'] = 'Create Account'
    self.crf.pack()

# Draw Widgets
def widgets(self):
    self.head = Label(self.master, text='LOGIN', font=('', 35), pady=10)
    self.head.pack()
    self.logf = Frame(self.master, padx=10, pady=10)
    Label(self.logf, text='Username: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
    Entry(self.logf, textvariable=self.username, bd=5, font=('', 15)).grid(row=0, column=1)
    Label(self.logf, text='Password: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
    Entry(self.logf, textvariable=self.password, bd=5, font=('', 15), show='*').grid(row=1, column=1)
    Button(self.logf, text=' Login ', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=self.login).grid()
    Button(self.logf, text=' Create Account ', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=self.cr).grid(row=2,
                                                                                                          column=1)
    self.logf.pack()

    self.crf = Frame(self.master, padx=10, pady=10)
    Label(self.crf, text='Username: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
    Entry(self.crf, textvariable=self.n_username, bd=5, font=('', 15)).grid(row=0, column=1)
    Label(self.crf, text='Password: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
    Entry(self.crf, textvariable=self.n_password, bd=5, font=('', 15), show='*').grid(row=1, column=1)
    Button(self.crf, text='Create Account', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=self.new_user).grid()
    Button(self.crf, text='Go to Login', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=self.log).grid(row=2,
                                                                                                     column=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   # Create Object
   # and setup window
   root = Tk()
   root.title('Login Form')
   # root.geometry('400x350+300+300')
   main(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

My error is :
       root.mainloop()
                     ^
       SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
 I have checked everything. Can't get over this problem. pls help. I have also looked into other's solution, couldn't find any help. I would be really grateful if someone could look into this matter.
Also attaching screenshot of my error:

[image]

Comment: There's a lot of code there and no stacktrace for us to go on. I suggest you start deleting things from your code until the error stops, and narrow down the problem that way.

Comment: A copy+paste of your code weren't able to reproduce the SyntaxError, voting to close accordingly. If your problem was indeed caused by what the answerer pointed out, you should check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7297888/6622817

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the last line there's a unicode character.

When running `.encode()` on your code it results in the following last line:

```
root.mainloop()\xef\xbb\xbf
```

You should remove the character somehow. Maybe by deleting the whole line.