# How to refer to perl arguments when looping through them?

Tags: perl

Hi I'm trying to use the code written in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712480/1740992 :

```
foreach (@ARGV){
   print "file: $_\n";
 # open your file here...
   #..do something
 # close your file
}
```

I don't know how to refer to the argument. When my scipt was just running on one file I open it by running:

```
$kml = "adair.kml";
open INPUT, "<$kml";
```

what do I replace my filename with?
I've tried `$ARGV[n]`

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already using it, [it is `$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables).

You can use a named variable instead with:

```
foreach my $foo (@ARGV){
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for my $arg (@ARGV) {
    open my $fh, '<', $arg or die "Cannot open '$arg': $!";
    # ...
    close $fh;
 }
```

Comment: So few lines, so much saner!

Answer (score 0):

Your code block:

```
$kml = "adair.kml";
open INPUT, "<$kml";
```

should be replaced with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $kml = $ARGV[0];
open my $input_fh, '<', $kml or die "Couldn't open $kml $!";
```

if your code is only going to run with one argument.