# Why do printf and sprintf behave differently when only given an array?

Tags: perl

```
sub do_printf  { printf @_ }
sub do_sprintf { print sprintf @_ }

do_printf("%s\n", "ok");  # prints ok
do_sprintf("%s\n", "ok"); # prints 2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [perldoc on sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

> Unlike printf, sprintf does not do
>   what you probably mean when you pass
>   it an array as your first argument.
>   The array is given scalar context, and
>   instead of using the 0th element of
>   the array as the format, Perl will use
>   the count of elements in the array as
>   the format, which is almost never
>   useful.

Answer (score 14):

`sprintf` has prototype `$@` while `printf` has prototype of `@`

Comment: But does anyone have an idea, why? Generally such unobvious things mean there is some DWIM implied here.

Comment: A guess out of nowhere: `sprintf` has prototype `($@)` because it can; `printf` has no prototype because (like `print`) it can take a bareword filehandle (e.g. `printf FH "format", ...` so it requires parser magic above and beyond what the prototype system can manage.

Answer (score 9):

See `codeholic`'s and `Mark`'s answers for the explanation as to why they behave differently.

As a workaround, simply do:

```
sub do_sprintf { print sprintf(shift, @_) }
```

Then,

```
sub do_printf  { printf @_ }
sub do_sprintf { print sprintf(shift, @_) }

do_printf("%s\n", "ok");  # prints ok
do_sprintf("%s\n", "ok2"); # prints ok2
```

Comment: not able to figure how to re-write this, so that sprintf output has all array contents: `sprintf("%-*s", 30,@arr)`

Comment: @rajeev, perhaps `sprintf("%-*s", 30, join(',', @arr))`?

Answer (score 1):

sprintf evaluates the array in scalar context. Your array has two elements, so it evaluates as "2" (without a trailing \n).

Comment: ...OK, thank you for stating the obvious, and the answer to the poster's question is?...

Answer (score 1):

*They do different things.* For `printf` the output is *to* a stream; for `sprintf` you want the string constructed. It handles the *formatting* (the *f*) of the print command. The main purpose for `printf` is to print out the value it constructs to a stream but with s(tring)printf(ormat) you're only trying to *create* the string, not print it.

`printf` returns the number of characters printed to a stream as feedback. Once characters are printed to a stream they've passed out of the logical structure of the program. Meanwhile, `sprintf` needs to hand you back a string. The most convenient way is as a return value--which because it is within the program structure can be inspected for length, or whether it contains any 'e's, or whatever you want.

Why *shouldn't* they behave differently?