# sprintf returns number of arguments instead of the string

Tags: perl, printf

I want to wrap the `sprintf` function for later string manipulation. The code is reduced to the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub myPrintf
{
    printf (@_);
    
    my $text = sprintf (@_);
    
    print "$text\n";
}

myPrintf("X%.3f Y%.3f\n", 1.223243, 4.567567);

my $t2 = sprintf("X%.3f Y%.3f\n", 1.223243, 4.567567);
print "$t2";
```

The Output is

```
X1.223 Y4.568
3
X1.223 Y4.568
```

Is the "3" printed in the second line? How can this be fixed?

I would expect:

```
X1.223 Y4.568
X1.223 Y4.568
X1.223 Y4.568
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: This is similar to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897817

Answer (score 5):

The builtin function `sprintf()` has a prototype. You can see this by running this code:

```
$ perl -E'say prototype("CORE::sprintf")'
$@
```

You can see that the prototype is `$@` - and that matches the [documentation for the function](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf) which says the function is called as `sprintf FORMAT, LIST`.

The `$` at the start of the prototype forces the first argument to be evaluated in scalar context. Evaluating an array in scalar context gives you the number of elements in the array - hence the 3 you are seeing.

The fix is to split the input array before passing it to `sprintf()`.

```
sub myPrintf
{
    my ($format, @data) = @_;
    printf (@_);

    my $text = sprintf ($format, @data);

    print "$text\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sprintf` operator behaves like a sub with the `$@` prototype.

```
$ perl -Mv5.14 -e'say prototype("CORE::sprintf") // "[none]"'
$@
```

As such, `@_` is being evaluated in scalar context. This produces the number of elements within.

Solution:

```perl
my $format = shift;
sprintf( $format, @_ )
```

```perl
sub myPrintF {
   my $format = shift;
   my $str = sprintf( $format, @_ );
   print( $str );
   return $str;
}
```