# What does &@ mean for sub?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the function declaration “sub function($$)” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485078/what-does-the-function-declaration-sub-function-mean)

```
sub t(&@) {
    print @_;
}
t {print 1};
```

I tried to change `&@` to `&$` and it will fail.

What's the lingo for it so that I can search?

Comment: See line 8 in the code example [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes)

Comment: Also see [this old rant](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=406231) about why you probably shouldn't use prototypes anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&@` is a subroutine prototype. This lets you create syntax similar to the builtin [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) function (accepts a *BLOCK* and then a *LIST*). The *LIST* can even be the empty list: `()`.

`&$` when used will force the second argument (which is mandatory) to be evaluated in scalar context. Since there is no second argument in `t {print 1};` it will fail to compile.

Read more about subroutine prototypes at: [`perldoc perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes).

Comment: What's the difference between `&$` and `&;$`?

Comment: The `;` makes the rest of the arguments optional.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear on what you want the code to do, but you are creating a prototype for your sub, see the [perldocs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes). The `&` means the sub `t` takes a block as the first argument and the `@` means the rest of the arguments are an array.

When you call your function, you are passing it one argument, the block `{print 1}` and that is what you are then printing out - the CODE reference as a string. The reason `&$` fails is you are not passing a second argument. That is fine for `&@` as the second argument is the empty array.

Comment: Whats with the drive-by downvotes for all of the answers?

Comment: Someone is working against the community, I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is "perl function prototypes".

Answer (score 0):

"Function prototype", http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes