# How can I pass two lists to a Perl subroutine?

Tags: perl, function, arguments

Is it possible to pass two lists to a `sub` in Perl, for example:

```
sub Foo {
 my(@list1,@list2) = @_;

}
```

I know I could make `@_` two lists, with each sublist being the desired argument, I'm just wondering if there is a cleaner way

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well if you want two **arrays** you could use a prototype:

```
sub foo (\@\@) {
   my $arr1 = shift;
   my $arr2 = shift;

   # Access arrays as references
}

foo( @wiz, @waz );  # @wiz and @waz won't be flattened.
```

But there are many ways to get around prototypes, and I prefer to avoid them in most places.  You can simply skip the prototype and manually pass references:

```
sub foo {
   my $arr1 = shift;
   my $arr2 = shift;

   # Access arrays as references
}

foo( \@wiz, \@waz ); # Pass in wiz/waz as refs
foo( [1,2,4],[3,5,6] );  # Hard coded arrays
```

If you haven't worked with references at all, check out [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for a nice tutorial.

Comment: it would seem that the prototype is a better solution, as it would not require the user to do anything special to pass the list arguments. thanks

Comment: @Mike, I would recommend against prototypes, since an experienced perl programmer will be more surprised by them than the requirement to pass a reference.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-function-prototypes-bad for more on why prototypes are frowned upon.

Comment: @Mike, I use prototypes soo often that I made an error in my prototype specification that I just realized.  So if you already tried my code sample and it didn't work, note the change in the prototype.

Comment: Indeed, prototypes are best avoided. You may also run into surprising results if you try to call a prototyped sub as an object method.

Comment: reference prototypes can be a bit annoying when you are trying to pass in a inline generated value without an intermediate array (output of `map` or `grep` for example). the non reference prototypes can be very useful though.  the latter `foo` example can also be called this way: `foo \\(@wiz, @waz)`

Comment: You have this really bad habit of highlighting the wrong answer by putting it first (and even mentioning it).

Comment: @Eric: maybe it's annoying because you're making it harder than it needs to be. Just use an anonymous array constructor around whatever is making the list:  [ map {} ... ]. Easy Peasy.

Comment: @brian d foy => passing an anonymous array to a function with a `(\@)` prototype is a syntax error. It needs to be `@{[ map {} ... ]}` ... which ultimately doesn't help with readability and is just working around what should be an entirely unambiguous situation that the lexer/parser just doesn't understand.

Comment: Well, that's one of the reasons you shouldn't use prototypes. I'm only talking about sane solutions.

Answer (score 5):

If you pass two lists by value ... you're going to get one big list in `@_`.

`my(@list1,@list2) = @_;` doesn't make any sense:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub test
{
    my (@a, @b) = @_;

    print "@a\n";
    print "@b\n";
}

my @array1 = (1,2,3);
my @array2 = (5,6,7);

test(@array1, @array2);
```

This will end up printing:

```
1 2 3 5 6 7
<blank line>
```

To pass two arrays, you'd need to pass them by reference:

```
test(\@array1, \@array2);
```

And in your sub you'd need to treat them as references:

```
sub test
{
    my ($arrayRef1, $arrayRef2) = @_;
    print "@$arrayRef1\n";
    print "@$arrayRef2\n";
}
```