# Map with Split & Trim in Perl

Tags: perl, dictionary, split, trim

How do I use map with the split function to trim the constituents: $a, $b, $c and $d; of $line?

```
my ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) = split(/\t/, $line);

# Perl trim function to remove whitespace from the start and end of the string
sub trim($)
{
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use prototypes the `($)` on your function unless you **need** them.

```
my ( $a, $b, $c, $d, $e ) =
  map {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $_}    ## Notice the `, $_` this is common
  , split(/\t/, $line, 5)
;
```

Don't forget in the above `s///` returns the replacement count -- not `$_`. So, we do that explicitly.

or more simply:

```
my @values = map {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $_}, split(/\t/, $line, 5), $line
```

Comment: I don't know why the downvote, but you've forgotten the g at the end in the final line.

Comment: Why do you recommend against prototypes?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-function-prototypes-bad , add to it, that no one else does, and they add line noise. You only need them if your trying to create a level of sugar that gives you a different non-perlish look or feel. They don't really handle much else, and they don't work at all on methods.

Comment: I suggest `map { s/^\s+|\s+$//gr } split('\t', $line)` usable from [perl 5.14](http://www.perl.com/pub/2011/05/new-features-of-perl-514-non-destructive-substitution.html)

Answer (score 3):

[`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) takes two inputs:

- an expression or block: this would be the [trim](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::Util) expression (you don't have to write your own -- it's on CPAN)
- and a list to operate on: this should be [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html)'s output:

```
use String::Util 'trim';
my @values = map { trim($_) } split /\t/, $line;
```

Comment: I'm nervous about introducing a dependence on a module which says "Final version. As of this version String::Util is no longer under development or being supported."

Comment: If we are going to install a CPAN module, we might as well use the one that does the job the best: [`String::Strip`](http://p3rl.org/String::Strip). See http://www.illusori.co.uk/perl/2010/03/05/advanced_benchmark_analysis_1.html

Comment: I haven't tried it, but the acid test for these kinds of modules is whether they strip out things like Unicode 0x3000 from the string. If not then maybe it is not a good replacement. Glancing at the source code, String::Strip uses the C function `isspace` to strip spaces and has no awareness of unicode, so it will behave differently from the above.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
my ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) = map {trim ($_)} (split(/\t/, $line));
```

By the way, it's a minor point, but you should not use $a and $b as variable names.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use "foreach" here.

```
foreach my $i ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) {
  $i=trim($i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for variety:

```
my @trimmed = grep { s/^\s*|\s*$//g } split /\t/, $line;
```

[`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) acts as a filter on lists. This is why the `\s+`s need to be changed to `\s*`s inside the regex. Forcing matches on 0 or more spaces prevents `grep` from filtering out items in the list that have no leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: But it wouldn't include segments that were surrounded by tabs with no spaces. `"\tspoon\t"` would be omitted.

Comment: @Axeman : From [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html):             "`\s` matches a whitespace character, the set `[\ \t\r\n\f]` and others." Besides, aren't we splitting on `\t` here ;)?

Comment: yes--but never mind, my eyes replaced `\s*` with my usual `\s+`. So the subst always matches and I don't know what I'm talking about. :D

Answer (score 0):

When I trim a string, I don't often want to keep the original. It would be nice to have the abstraction of a sub but also not have to fuss with temporary values.

It turns out that we can do just this, as [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) explains:

> Any arguments passed in show up in the array `@_`. Therefore, if you called a function with two arguments, those would be stored in `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`. The array `@_` is a local array, but its elements are aliases for the actual scalar parameters. In particular, if an element `$_[0]` is updated, the corresponding argument is updated (or an error occurs if it is not updatable).

In your case, `trim` becomes

```
sub trim {
  for (@_) {
    s/^ \s+  //x;
    s/  \s+ $//x;
  }
  wantarray ? @_ : $_[0];
}
```

Remember that `map` and `for` are cousins, so with the loop in `trim`, you no longer need `map`. For example

```
my $line = "1\t 2\t3 \t 4 \t  5  \n";    
my ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) = split(/\t/, $line);    

print "BEFORE: [", join("] [" => $a, $b, $c, $d), "]\n";
trim $a, $b, $c, $d;
print "AFTER:  [", join("] [" => $a, $b, $c, $d), "]\n";
```

Output:

```
BEFORE: [1] [ 2] [3 ] [ 4 ]
AFTER:  [1] [2] [3] [4]
```

Comment: Could you explain the '=>' usage of join? I've never seen that before?

Comment: @10rd_n3r0, I'll take a stab at it, the first parameter in join is a special one, and the others are all treated the same, the "fat comma" ( `=>` ) just gives better visual separation than `,`. I've used it myself for that reason. Such as in this case `keyword => qw<a list of words>` nothing differentiates them in the list created, but I'm showing the way I'm thinking of them. I use if for those times that I want the visual separation to portray what the semantics.

Comment: @10rd I used it for visual separation as @Axeman described. As I was writing it up, I originally had `join(", " => ...)`, and whenever the separator contains a comma, I like to use the fat comma for readability.

Comment: More readable, perhaps : `print "BEFORE: ". join ' ', map { '['.$_.']' } ($a, $b, $c, $d);`