# perl from user input of a number, add each digit

Tags: perl

I am very new to perl and I am learning this is not like c++. So The user will enter a number of any length, and I want to add each digit and print the sum.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter a number :";

my $num = <STDIN>;

my @array = $num;
my $sum=0;
for my $arr (@array){

    $sum += $arr;

print $sum;
}
```

For example the user enters 1234, the sum: 10

the actual result I get is 1234.

Comment: When you are using `use warnings;`, you don't need `-w` in shebang line. Purpose of both is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Just need to add two lines

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter a number :";

my $num = <STDIN>;

#You missed out to remove the entermark at the end
chomp($num); my $newnum = "0";

$newnum += $_  for split//, $num;

print $newnum;
```

> Note: *I didn't override or not considering the method what you have followed however I just did what I know in perl*.

[Further More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162983/map-with-split-trim-in-perl)

Comment: Obviously, I don't know how to explain this really in theoretically. Since I am also learner in perl just little bit having some idea while doing in practically.

Comment: i'm kind of new to perl too, 
Is there a difference between the syntax  `split //, $num` and `split('', $num)`?
I was used to the second one but I now see the first one everywhere

Comment: Don't use `map` when you mean `for`.

Comment: @Borodin: This is for me then I couldn't understand the comment... Please just give in detail.

Comment: `map` is for "mapping" one list to another. `map { $newnum += $_ } split //, $num` should be `$newnum += $_ for split //, $num`.

Comment: @Borodin: Thanks I understood and updated the answer.

Comment: @Flying_whale: the two calls to `split` are syntactically identical, you can omit the parentheses on perl's built-in functions (and your own on certain conditions). Adding them may be useful for clarity in longer expressionts though.

Answer (score 4):

You need to break the input string `$num` into separate digits. Try replacing `my @array = $num` with `my @array = split //, $num`. Read more by running `perldoc -f split`.

In Perl both strings and numbers are classified as `SCALAR`s. A scalar is automatically treated as a number if arithmetic operations (like `+`) are done with them, so the summation inside the `for` loop works as expected.

Comment: It is also first checked whether it [looks_like_number](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#looks_like_number)