# How does func2 know the context?

Tags: perl

```
func1(func2);
```

As we know Perl needs to know the context to evaluate,but in the above case how does `func2` know it's in scalar or list context?

Comment: I think it will be scalar unless you include a prototype (ala `sub func1($$$)`) for `func1`

Comment: @Ben Jackson: No, in the absence of a prototype `func2` would be called in list context -- it's part of the *list* of arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If func1 does not have a prototype (or a `@` prototype), it will be list context. If func1 has a prototype of `$`, then it will be scalar context.

Caveat: please do not use prototypes, they're [evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently. it's list.

```
$ perl
sub f1 { print "called f1\n" } 
sub f2 { print "called f2\n"; print wantarray ? "list": "scalar"; print "\n"; }
f1(f2);
^d
called f2
list
called f1
```

Why? That's another question entirely - I assume because function params are implicitly lists come what may.

Comment: You may want to complete the picture here by showing what happens when `f1` defines the prototype.

Comment: Re "Why?", in what context do you think a list of arguments should be constructed?