# How is the map function in Perl implemented?

Tags: perl, dictionary

Is `map` function in Perl written in Perl? I just can not figure out how to implement it. Here is my attempt:

```
use Data::Dumper;

sub Map {
    my ($function, $sequence) = @_;

    my @result;
    foreach my $item (@$sequence) {
        my $_ = $item;
        push @result, $function->($item);
    }
    return @result
}

my @sample = qw(1 2 3 4 5);
print Dumper Map(sub { $_ * $_ }, \@sample);
print Dumper map({ $_ * $_ } @sample);
```

`$_` in `$function` is undefined as it should be, but how `map` overcomes this?

Comment: No, but you encourage more people to answer your question. Accepted marks and upvotes are how we say "thanks" here. And more importantly, people in the future will arrive in those questions looking for a solution and will know which one is the correct. This might help http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/160504

Comment: I see. I typed "thank you" in comments before

Comment: @alex - aside from benefits that sidyll mentioned: Comment gives someone a nice feeling. Accept gives the answerer 15 rep points (and 2 rep points to you :)

Comment: @DVK An accepted answer will typically also give some extra upvotes, some nice cred, and some nice green color in your score sheet. =)

Comment: Also read Book Higher Order Perl, where they talk about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`map` has some special syntax, so you can't entirely implement it in pure-perl, but this would come pretty close to it (as long as you're using the block form of map):

```
sub Map(&@) {
    my ($function, @sequence) = @_;

    my @result;
    foreach my $item (@sequence) {
        local $_ = $item;
        push @result, $function->($item);
    }
    return @result
}

use Data::Dumper;
my @sample = qw(1 2 3 4 5);
print Dumper Map { $_ * $_ } @sample;
print Dumper map { $_ * $_ } @sample;
```

`$_` being undefined is overcome by using `local $_` instead of `my $_`. Actually you almost never want to use `my $_` (even though you do want to use it on almost all other variables).

Adding the `(&@)` prototype allows you not to specify `sub` in front of the block. Again, you almost [never want to use prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad) but this is a valid use of them.

Comment: @leon-timmermans, how does the `&@` prototype still fail to allow for a pure-Perl implementation on account of special syntax?

Comment: @RichardSimões: It doesn't allow for jokes like `map 2*$_, 1..10`. Note that the first argument is not a block but a rather special expression.

Answer (score 5):

While the accepted answer implements a `map`-like function, it does NOT do it in the way perl would.  An important part of `for`, `foreach`, `map`, and `grep` is that the `$_` they provide to you is always an alias to the values in the argument list.  This means that calling something like `s/a/b/` in any of those constructs will modify the elements they were called with.  This allows you to write things like:

```
my ($x, $y) = qw(foo bar);

$_ .= '!' for $x, $y;

say "$x $y"; # foo! bar!

map {s/$/!!!/} $x, $y;

say "$x $y"; # foo!!!! bar!!!!
```

Since in your question, you have asked for `Map` to use array references rather than arrays, here is a version that works on array refs that is as close to the builtin `map` as you can get in pure Perl.

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;
use strict;

sub Map (&\@) {
    my ($code, $array) = splice @_;
    my @return;
    push @return, &$code for @$array;
    @return
}

my @sample = qw(1 2 3 4 5);
say join ', ' => Map { $_ * $_ } @sample; # 1, 4, 9, 16, 25
say join ', ' => map { $_ * $_ } @sample; # 1, 4, 9, 16, 25
```

In `Map`, the `(&\@)` prototype tells perl that the `Map` bareword will be parsed with different rules than a usual subroutine.  The `&` indicates that the first argument will either be a bare block `Map {...} NEXT` or it will be a literal code reference `Map \&somesub, NEXT`.  Note the comma between the arguments in the latter version.  The `\@` prototype indicates that the next argument will start with `@` and will be passed in as an array reference.

Finally, the `splice @_` line empties `@_` rather than just copying the values out.  This is so that the `&$code` line will see an empty `@_` rather than the args `Map` received.  The reason for `&$code` is that it is the fastest way to call a subroutine, and is as close to the multicall calling style that `map` uses as you can get without using C.  This calling style is perfectly suited for this usage, since the argument to the block is in `$_`, which does not require any stack manipulation.

In the code above, I cheat a little bit and let `for` do the work of localizing `$_`.   This is good for performance, but to see how it works, here is that line rewritten:

```
    for my $i (0 .. $#$array) {   # for each index
        local *_ = \$$array[$i];  # install alias into $_
        push @return, &$code;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My [Object::Iterate](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Object%3a%3aIterate) module is an example of what you are trying to do.