# How can I pass optional parameters to a Perl function?

Tags: perl, subroutine

I want to pass several parameters, one of which is optional, to a function. The only way to do it that I know is using a list (@) as a parameter. Thus, it contents nothing or one element (will never be undef), so that I can use the following code:

```
sub someFunction($$@) {
    my ($oblig_param1, $oblig_param2, $option_param) = @_;

    # ...
}
```

This code works, but I feel that maybe it's not the best workaround.
Are there any other ways to do it?

Comment: Are you sure you need the prototype?

Comment: TLP, we are using prototypes as it is more demonstrative.

Comment: In addition to TLP answer take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad/297265#297265

Comment: I disagree. Prototypes will only serve to confuse things. If you want clarity, add a comment.

Comment: **Matteo**, thank you for the link: a great explanation there.

Comment: **TLP**, I'm not much of a Perl programmer so far. Prototypes are a bit confusing after C/C++. But with your detailed answers learning Perl won't take me so long :-)

Comment: @evgeny9 StackOverflow is a great place to learn new things. =) I learn new things most every day, and I did not think that was possible.

Comment: @TLP, yes, now I see. But at first, I just didn't expect such a bunch of qualified and fast answers!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a semicolon in the prototype to indicate the end of the required parameters:

```
sub someFunction($$;$) {
  my ( $oblig_param1, $oblig_param2, $option_param ) = @_;
  ...
}
```

The `;` is optional before a `@` or `%`, which, according to [the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes), "gobbles up everything else".

As [DVK points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124138/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-to-a-perl-function#comment9968330_8124190) in a comment (and TLP emphasizes in another answer here), you are probably best off simply avoiding prototypes:

```
sub someFunction {
  my ( $oblig_param1, $oblig_param2, $option_param ) = @_;
  ...
}
```

Perl prototypes have their uses (mostly to supply implicit context coercion to arguments, as Perl's built-in functions do). They should **not** be used as a mechanism to check that function are called with the correct number and type of arguments.

Comment: @Ted - I didn't DV, but my best guess is that because you omitted the most important sentence required for a good answer involving prototypes: "If you **need** to write a function that acts like a built-in, use a prototype. Otherwise, **don't use prototypes**" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad/297265

Answer (score 42):

[Prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) (the `($$@)` part of your sub declaration) are optional themselves. They have a very specific use, and if you don't know what it is, it is better to not use it. From perlsub:

> ...the intent of this feature is primarily to let you define subroutines
>   that work like built-in functions

Just remove the prototype from your sub declaration, and you can use whatever arguments you like.

```
sub someFunction {
    my ( $oblig_param1, $oblig_param2, $option_param ) = @_;
    if (defined $option_param) {
        # do optional things
    }
    $option_param //= "default optional value";
    ....
}
```

Comment: thank you. So, if I'm writing a Perl module, that'll be used by my colleagues, I should use prototypes?

Comment: Like I said in my comment, if you want clarity, add a comment instead. Don't use prototypes unless you specifically want the functionality that prototypes provide.

Comment: Usually, you shouldn't!

See [Far More Than Everything You've Ever Wanted to Know about Prototypes in Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861966)

Answer (score 16):

It is a good idea to group parameters in a `$parameter` hashref. This is especially useful if several options (mandatory or optional) need to be provided.

To access any parameter, simply use `$parameter->{oblig1}` or `$$parameter{option2}`.

Passing hashrefs make it especially convenient when developing, so when the need for `$oblig3` comes along, the ordering of the arguments changes neither at the caller nor the sub itself. Compare before and after:

---

```
# BEFORE $oblig3

--------------------------+-------------------------
# Caller                  | # Sub
--------------------------+-------------------------
someFunc( $oblig1,        | sub {
          $oblig2,        |   my ( $oblig1,
          $option1 );     |        $oblig2,
                          |        $option1 ) = @_;
                          | }
--------------------------+-------------------------

# AFTER $oblig3

--------------------------+-------------------------
# Caller                  | # Sub
--------------------------+-------------------------
someFunc( $oblig1,        | sub {
          $oblig2,        |   my ( $oblig1,
          $oblig3,        |        $oblig2,
          $option1 );     |        $oblig3,
                          |        $option1 ) = @_;
                          | }
--------------------------+-------------------------
```

The argument order changes at both caller and sub, so order needs to be maintained and respected.

Using hashrefs, there is no need to worry about argument order:

```
--------------------------+-------------------------
# Caller                  | # Sub
--------------------------+-------------------------
someFunc({ oblig1  => 1   | sub {
           oblig2  => 2   |   my ( $params ) = @_;
           option1 => 1   |   # No changes to
           oblig3  => 7   |   # argument passing
         });              |  }
                          |
--------------------------+-------------------------
```

---

Depending on the design needs of the subroutine, the following subroutine argument patterns could be utilized:

1. **`my ( $mandatory_parameters, $optional_parameters ) = @_;`**

This pattern is useful if there are several of each. The beauty of this approach is that `$optional_parameters` is undefined if not passed, so the default case could be executed `if  ! $optional_parameters;`

Note that the mandatory parameters will need to be checked subsequently:

```
    for ( qw/ a b c / ) { 
        die "Missing '$_' parameter\n"
          unless exists $mandatory_parameters->{$_};
    }
```

2. **`my ( $parameters ) = @_;`**

Useful if there are few or no mandatory parameters.

It is also extremely effective if parameters are passed to simply modify default behavior. By defining `$default_parameters` in the scope of the package, the defaults can be loaded by a subsequent one-liner unless a parameter was explicitly passed:

```
`$parameters = { %$default_parameters, %$parameters };`
```

Comment: **Zaid**, thank you, but I think that using hash links is a bit early for me.

Comment: @evgeny9 : If you're willing to play around with prototypes, I suggest you take the time to understand hashes in a bit more detail. It's not that difficult, trust me! :)