# How to pass optional arguments to a function

Tags: perl, function, subroutine

I'm trying to make a function for a module accept optional arguments in the form of:

```
function(arg1, optional1 => opt1, optional2 => opt2, ..);
```

Yet I can't find anywhere that shows a good explanation how to do this. I came up with the following solution to accept `email`, `alpha` and `html` arguments, but it's extremely convoluted and I can't believe there isn't a shorter way to accomplish this:

```
sub test
{
    my ($s, @args) = @_;
    my $alpha = 1;
    my $html = 0;
    my $email = 0;
    for(my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@args); $i++)
    {
        if($args[$i] eq "alpha")
        {
            $i++;
            $alpha = $args[$i];
        }
        elsif($args[$i] eq "email")
        {
            $i++;
            $email = $args[$i];
        }
        elsif($args[$i] eq "html")
        {
            $i++;
            $html = $args[$i];
        }
    }
    return ($alpha, $email, $html);
}

my ($a, $b, $c) = test("stuff", ndhgffs => 1, email => 1, alpha => 0);

print $a . $b . $c;
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the answer below and comments below that, this solved it:

```
sub test
{
   my ($s, %opts) = @_;
   my $email = $opts{'email'} // 0;
   my $alpha = $opts{'alpha'} // 1;
   my $html = $opts{'html'} // 0;
   return ($alpha, $email, $html);
}
```

Comment: The other way of doing it is passing a hash reference.

Comment: Is `alpha` boolean? If so, `$opts{'alpha'} // 1` is error prone. Consider `$opts{'no_alpha'} // 0` (or just `$opts{'no_alpha'}`).

Comment: OT but how would one handle this with function signatures? Could post 5.20 `use experimental 'signatures'` offer a cleaner "idiom" for this sort of thing? It seems like grabbing things from `@_` is pretty neat/clean and self documenting when you have complicated function arguments ... TIMTOWTDI && ♥ perl :-)

Comment: In this example yes the functions would be Boolean, although I assume `//` should work with strings as well..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass optional parameters to a Perl function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124138/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-to-a-perl-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sub function {
   my $arg1 = shift;
   my $arg2 = shift;
   my %opts = @_;
   my $optional1 = delete($opts{$optional1});
   my $optional2 = delete($opts{$optional2});
   croak("Unrecognized parameters ".join(' ', keys(%opts))) if %opts;
   ...
}
```

or

```
sub function {
   my ($arg1, $arg2, %opts) = @_;
   my $optional1 = delete($opts{$optional1});
   my $optional2 = delete($opts{$optional2});
   croak("Unrecognized parameters ".join(' ', keys(%opts))) if %opts;
   ...
}
```

---

Notes:

- If you don't want to bother checking for unrecognized options, you don't need `delete`.
- You can easily assign default values when an argument is omitted or undef using

  ```
  my $arg = delete($opts{$arg}) // 'default';   # Perl 5.10+
  ```

Comment: Should one use `delete` in this case?

Comment: Habit. It allows `die "Unrecognized args" if %opts;`. If you don't use that check, you don't need `delete`.

Comment: Shouldn't have edited your comment, your original one was good, I didn't know about '//'.

Comment: @Dendory I'm pretty sure `//` is a post `5.10` thing - IOW it's a new modern perl feature from the early part of the millenium(does that make it a mature in Perl terms?). If you maintain business critical applications running on an untouchable `5.8.*` installation it's normal you would not know about it ... in fact you maybe should try to forget ;-)

Comment: Actually there might have been patches for 5.8.* or `//` could have been back ported.

Comment: @G. Cito, Someone still using 5.8 won't be patching it to add `//`. (A patch actually does exist.)

Answer (score 0):

If the subroutine arguments are copied from the values of `@_` and assigned to variables for the function "in order of appearance", then your function could be written to either have defaults you could set with the [defined OR operator `//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) or, if those values are truly optional and not always needed, then you could assign a placeholder value (*e.g.* `not_set`) that you then remove/delete after the function reads in its arguments from `@_` with something like:

```
for (keys %opthash){ if ($opthash{$_} =~ /not_set/)  {delete $opthash{$_} }}
```

I'm not sure this is the most efficient approach if this function is one that is used a lot.