# Can I alias an object method to different methods on different objects?

Tags: perl

More easily explained with an example:

```
my $o = SpecialEffects->new( "config" => 'a' );
my $p = SpecialEffects->new( "config" => 'b' );

$o->sound(); # aliased to fizz(); same as $o->fizz()
$p->sound(); # aliased to clonk(); same as $p->clonk()
```

Is it possible to do this in Perl? Perhaps using some typeglob or coderef trickery?

I'm trying to keep the `SpecialEffects` interface simple. I'd prefer not to start building an object hierarchy. The `sound()` method is what's exposed, only its behaviour can be configured slightly.

I already know that you can alias with `*sound = \&fizz;` but that is a global thing as far as I know, and I'd like it encapsulated in the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple, easy, non-wizardry way is to just store a method name in your `SpecialEffects` object, set it according to whatever you want to happen, and call it from `sound()`.

```
package SpecialEffects;

sub new {
    my $type = shift;
    my %options = @_;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $type;
    if($options{config} eq 'a') {
        $self->{sound_method} = 'fizz';
    } elsif($options{config} eq 'b') {
        $self->{sound_method} = 'clonk';
    }
    return $self;
}

sub sound {
    my $self = shift;
    my $method_name = $self->{sound_method};
    $self->$method_name();
}

sub fizz {
    print "fizz\n";
}

sub clonk {
    print "clonk\n";
}
```

You can store and use coderefs about as easily as method names, if you want to be more wizardly.

```
package SpecialEffects;

sub new {
    my $type = shift;
    my %options = @_;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $type;
    if($options{config} eq 'a') {
        $self->{sound_code} = $self->can('fizz');
    } elsif($options{config} eq 'b') {
        $self->{sound_code} = $self->can('clonk');
    }
    return $self;
}   

sub sound {
    my $self = shift;
    my $code = $self->{sound_code};
    $self->$code();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using prototypes, especially not on methods.  Perl doesn't even do prototype checking on method calls, so they're completely useless.

Comment: @cjm: Is there something actively *wrong* with them?  It hadn't occurred to me that there would be a reason to object to using them in simply documentary form, with an eye to the possibility that call checking might catch up sometime.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/297034/8355) for reasons you shouldn't use them (except in special circumstances).  If you want to document the parameters to your method, use a comment (or POD).

Comment: f you want documentation then write documentation. Adding code that is bad practice and has no effect isn't helpful. Prototypes don't make Perl do type checking - they enforce a *context* on the run time parameters.

Comment: Mmmkay.  I HOPE YOU'RE ALL HAPPY NOW.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't create per-instance methods without storing references in a hash (`$o->{sound}()` can be done).

Methods are bound to classes, which correspond to perl packages. So you should alialise `*SpecialEffects::sound = &SpecialEffects::fizz`. This applies to all objects of one class. Sorry this is not javascript etc, I hate this myself...

(You could do some semi-wizadry and create a package `SpecialEffects::clonky` on the fly (during runtime), which just includes the `sound` alias for `clonk` and subclasses `SpecialEffects`. Then rebless your reference. This is effectively your unwanted hierarchy, but you don't have to actually make the .pm files

EDIT: I'm not sure how exactly this is done, but it goes along these lines ↓ *If* it works, this is a semi-elegant solution (it will mess up your name space)

```
sub whatSoundShallIMake {
  my ($self, $sound) = @_;
  no strict 'refs';
  my $newPackageName = "SpecialEffects::make$sound";
  *{"$newPackageName\::sound"} = &{"SpecialEffects::$sound"}; # make the alias
  @{"$newPackageName\::ISA"} = qw(SpecialEffects); # subclass
  return bless $self, $newPackageName; # rebless
}

say ref $o;
# prints "SpecialEffects"
$o = whatSoundShallIMake($o, "fizz");
say ref $0;
# prints  "SpecialEffects::makefizz"
```

)

Comment: I was afraid that a coderef in the object hash would be the only way to go. I would have preferred to keep the method call plain and direct. Your wizardry sounds interesting though I do not understand it ...

Comment: I added some example code for dynamic packages, but @chaos' solution using `&sound` to look up the effective sub in the object's hash is faster, more adaptable, safer and more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Moose](http://moose.perl.org):

```
package SpecialEffects;
use Moose;

has '_method' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'CodeRef');

around BUILDARGS => sub {
    my ($orig, $class, %args) = @_;
    my %map = (a => 'fizz', b => 'clonk');
    if (my $config = delete $args{config}) {
        $args{_method} = $class->can($map{$config});
    }
    return $class->$orig(%args);
};

sub sound {shift->_method->(@_)}
sub fizz  {return 'fizz';}
sub clonk {return 'clonk';}
1;
```

---

```
use Test::More;
use SpecialEffects;

my $o = SpecialEffects->new(config => 'a');
is($o->sound, 'fizz');
my $p = SpecialEffects->new(config => 'b');
is($p->sound, 'clonk');

done_testing;
```

---

Code credits go to omega in [#moose](http://irc.perl.org), commenting:

> <omega> but not really "clean" :p
>
> <omega> and not that Moosey
>
> <omega> Probably better to apply a role

Comment: That's neat! Probably too heavyweight for my tiny application. But I'm going to take a look at Moose now, thanks.