# "Too many arguments" when passing an array to Perl sub?

Tags: perl

I have a function below in perl

```
sub create_hash()
{
my @files = @_;

        foreach(@files){
         if(/.text/)
         {

         open($files_list{$_},">>$_") || die("This file will not open!");

         }
      }

}
```

I am calling this function by passing an array argument like below:

```
create_hash( @files2);
```

The array has got around 38 values in it.
But i am getting compilation errors:

```
Too many arguments for main::create_hash at ....
```

what is the wrong that i am doing here?

my perl version is :

```
This is perl, v5.8.4 built for i86pc-solaris-64int
(with 36 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Comment: Take off the `()`? (As in `sub create_hash { .. }`)

Comment: what happens if you call your function like:   create_hash( files2);

(without "@" sign )

Comment: @ pst if i remove them error is : Array found where operator expected at process.pl line 71, at end of line
        (Do you need to predeclare create_hash?)
syntax error at process.pl line 71, near "create_hash @files2"

Comment: @peter Wrong spot: remove at sub-declaration, not invocation. Although `create_hash @files2;` should still be valid *without* the prototype .. (did a line carry-over?)

Comment: BTW, 5.8.4 is a *really* ancient version of Perl (although that has nothing to do with your problem).  You should really consider installing a newer version.  [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App%3A%3Aperlbrew) can help with that.

Comment: I am not an admin. i can just use the perl available for coding.

Comment: With perlbrew, you don't need to be an admin to install a new version of Perl for your own use.  All you need is a suitable C toolchain and enough disk space.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
sub create_hash()
{
```

The `()` is a [prototype](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes).  In this case, it indicates that `create_hash` takes no parameters.  When you try to pass it some, Perl complains.

It should look like

```
sub create_hash
{
```

In general, [you should not use prototypes with Perl functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/297034/8355).  They aren't like prototypes in most other languages.  They do have uses, but that's a fairly advanced topic in Perl.

Comment: God bless . was breaking my head :)

Answer (score -3):

May use array reference as:

```
sub create_hash {
    my ($files) = @_;
    foreach(@{$files)){
      ...
    }
}

create_hash(\@files2);
```

Comment: One *could* use array-refs, but it would still generate an error with `sub create_hash() { rest_of_that_code }` ..

Comment: @pst: not "sub create_hash() {", it's "sub create_hash {"

Comment: @cdtits, while your solution works, you failed to explain why Peter's code didn't work in the first place.

Comment: @cdtits That's my point -- the declaration is different. Switching to an array-ref is only secondary :)

Comment: @pst: then why comment on your use of an array reference but not mention the prototyping at all?