# Perl - Two questions regarding proper syntax for dereferencing

Tags: perl, syntax, dereference

as a newbie I am trying to explore perl data structures using this material from atlanta perl mongers, avaliable here [Perl Data Structures](http://perlcabal.org/~util/YAPC/YAPC_2011_data_structures/perl_data_structures.pdf)

Here is the sample code that I've writen, `01.pl` is the same as `02.pl` but `01.pl` contains additional two pragmas: `use strict; use warnings;`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %name = (name=>"Linus", forename=>"Torvalds");
my @system = qw(Linux FreeBSD Solaris NetBSD);

sub passStructure{
  my ($arg1,$arg2)=@_;

  if (ref($arg1) eq "HASH"){
    &printHash($arg1);
  }
  elsif (ref($arg1) eq "ARRAY"){
    &printArray($arg1);
  }

  if (ref($arg2) eq "HASH"){
    &printHash($arg2);
  }
  elsif (ref($arg2) eq "ARRAY"){
    &printArray($arg2);
  }
}

sub printArray{
  my $aref = $_[0];

  print "@{$aref}\n";
  print "@{$aref}->[0]\n";
  print "$$aref[0]\n";          
  print "$aref->[0]\n";
}

sub printHash{
  my $href = $_[0];

  print "%{$href}\n";
  print "%{$href}->{'name'}\n";
  print "$$href{'name'}\n";
  print "$href->{'name'}\n";
}

&passStructure(\@system,\%name);
```

There are several points mentioned in above document that I misunderstood:

**1st**
Page 44 mentions that those two syntax constructions: `"$$href{'name'}"` and `"$$aref[0]"` shouldn't never ever been used for accessing values. Why ? Seems in my code they are working fine (see bellow), moreover perl is complaining about using `@{$aref}->[0]` as deprecated, so which one is correct ?

**2nd**
Page 45 mentions that without `"use strict"` and using `"$href{'SomeKey'}"` when `"$href->{'SomeKey'}"` should be used, the `%href` is created implictly. So if I understand it well, both following scripts should print "Exists"

```
    [pista@HP-PC temp]$ perl -ale 'my %ref=(SomeKey=>'SomeVal'); print $ref{'SomeKey'}; print "Exists\n" if exists $ref{'SomeKey'};'
    SomeVal
    Exists

    [pista@HP-PC temp]$ perl -ale '                              print $ref{'SomeKey'}; print "Exists\n" if exists $ref{'SomeKey'};'
```

but second wont, why ?

Output of two beginning mentioned scripts:

```
[pista@HP-PC temp]$ perl 01.pl 
Using an array as a reference is deprecated at 01.pl line 32.
Linux FreeBSD Solaris NetBSD
Linux
Linux
Linux
%{HASH(0x1c33ec0)}
%{HASH(0x1c33ec0)}->{'name'}
Linus
Linus
[pista@HP-PC temp]$ perl 02.pl 
Using an array as a reference is deprecated at 02.pl line 32.
Linux FreeBSD Solaris NetBSD
Linux
Linux
Linux
%{HASH(0x774e60)}
%{HASH(0x774e60)}->{'name'}
Linus
Linus
```

Answer (score 5):

Many people think `$$aref[0]` is ugly and `$aref->[0]` not ugly.  Others disagree;  there is nothing wrong with the former form.

`@{$aref}->[0]`, on the other hand, is a mistake that happens to work but is deprecated and may not continue to.

You may want to read http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

A package variable `%href` is created simply by mentioning such a hash without `use strict "vars"` in effect, for instance by leaving the `->` out of `$href->{'SomeKey'}`. That doesn't mean that particular key is created.

Update: looking at the Perl Best Practices reference (a book that inspired much more slavish adoption and less actual thought than the author intended), it is recommending the `->` form specifically to avoid the possibility of leaving off a sigil, leading to the problem mentioned on p45.

Answer (score 3):

Perl has normal datatypes, and *references* to data types. It is important that you are aware of the differerence between  them, both in their meaning, and in their syntax.

```
Type   |Normal Access | Reference Access | Debatable Reference Access
=======+==============+==================+===========================
Scalar | $scalar      | $$scalar_ref     |
Array  | $array[0]    | $arrayref->[0]   | $$arrayref[0]
Hash   | $hash{key}   | $hashref->{key}  | $$hashref{key}
Code   | code()       | $coderef->()     | &$coderef()
```

The reason why accessing hashrefs or arrayrefs with the `$$foo[0]` syntax can be considered bad is that (1) the double sigil looks confusingly like a scalar ref access, and (2) this syntax hides the fact that references are used. The de**ref**erencing arrow `->` is clear in its intent. I covered the reason why using the `&` sigil is bad in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14101945/1521179).

The `@{$aref}->[0]` is extremely wrong, because you are dereferencing a reference to an array (which cannot, by definition, be a reference itself), and then dereferencing the first element of that array with the arrow. See the above table for the right syntax.

Interpolating hashes into strings seldom makes sense. The stringification of a hash denotes the number of filled and available buckets, and so can tell you about the load. This isn't useful in most cases. Also, not treating the `%` character as special in strings allows you to use `printf`…

Another interesting thing about Perl data structures is to know when a new entry in a hash or array is created. In general, accessing a value does *not* create a slot in that hash or array, except when you are using the value as reference.

```
my %foo;
$foo{bar}; # access, nothing happens
say "created at access" if exists $foo{bar};
$foo{bar}[0]; # usage as arrayref
say "created at ref usage" if exists $foo{bar};
```

Output: `created at ref usage`.

Actually, the arrayref spings into place, because you can use `undef` values as references in certain cases. This arrayref then populates the slot in the hash.

Without `use strict 'refs'`, the variable (but not a slot in that variable) springs into place, because global variables *are* just entries in a hash that represents the namespace. `$foo{bar}` is the same as `$main::foo{bar}` is the same as `$main::{foo}{bar}`.

Answer (score 1):

The major advantage of the `$arg->[0]` form over the `$$arg[0]` form, is that it's much clearer with the first type as to what is going on... `$arg` is an ARRAYREF and you're accessing the 0th element of the array it refers to.

At first reading, the second form could be interpreted as `${$arg}[0]` (dereferencing an ARRAYREF) or `${$arg[0]}` (dereferencing whatever the first element of `@arg` is.

Naturally, only one interpretation is correct, but we all have those days (or nights) where we're looking at code and we can't quite remember what order operators and other syntactic devices work in. Also, the confusion would compound if there were additional levels of dereferencing.

Defensive programmers will tend to err towards efforts to make their intentions explicit and I would argue that `$arg->[0]` is a much more explicit representation of the intention of that code.

As to the automatic creation of hashes... it's only the hash that would be created (so that the Perl interpreter and check to see if the key exists). The key itself is not created (naturally... you wouldn't want to create a key that you're checking for... but you may need to create the bucket that would hold that key, if the bucket doesn't exist. The process is called autovivification and you can read more about it [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=691557).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be accessing the array as: @{$aref}[0] or $aref->[0].

a `print` statement does not instantiate an object. What is meant by the implicit creation is you don't need to predefine the variable before assigning to it. Since `print` does not assign the variable is not created.