# Perl Google Yahoo And etc Engine didn't bring results, Need help perl expert

Tags: perl, irc

> I make the scanner using perl, but when i try to test the script i got blank results on the some engine, didn't give me results, may someone help me to check the script where line is wrong writing in perl?

Thanks

```
sub google() {
my @list;
my $key = $_[0];
for (my $i=0; $i<=1000; $i+=100){
    my $search = ("http://www.google.com/search?q=".key($key)."&num=100&filter=0&start=".$i);
    my $res = search_engine_query($search);
    while ($res =~ m/<a href=\"?http:\/\/([^>\"]*)\//g) {
        my $link = $1;
        if ($link !~ /google/){
            my @grep = links($link);
            push(@list,@grep);
        }
    }
}
return @list;
```

}

```
sub search_engine() {
my (@total,@clean);
my $chan = $_[0];
my $bug = $_[1];
my $dork = $_[2];
my $engine = $_[3];
my $logo = $_[4];
if ($engine eq "GooGLe") { my @google = google($dork); push(@total,@google); }
if ($engine eq "AllTheWeb") { my @alltheweb = alltheweb($dork); push(@total,@alltheweb); }
if ($engine eq "Bing") { my @bing = bing($dork); push(@total,@bing); }
if ($engine eq "ALtaViSTa") { my @altavista = altavista($dork); push(@total,@altavista); }
if ($engine eq "AsK") { my @ask = ask($dork); push(@total,@ask); }
if ($engine eq "UoL") { my @uol = uol($dork); push(@total,@uol); }
if ($engine eq "YahOo") { my @yahoo = yahoo($dork); push(@total,@yahoo); }
@clean = clean(@total);
&msg("$chan","$logo(7@2$engine15)12 Total:4 (".scalar(@total).")12 Clean:4 (".scalar(@clean).")");
return @clean;
```

}

```
if ($engine =~ /google/i) {
    if (my $pid = fork) { waitpid($pid, 0); }
    else { if (fork) { exit; } else {
        &lfc($chan,$bug,$dork,"GooGLe");
    } exit; }
}
```

You can download [n0body Scanner](http://www.luckmt.com/woot.txt) at here.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you are using a zero-argument prototype for a function that you pass an argument to. [Don't do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad)

For another, are you inspecting the response whenever you are unhappy with the results? Is the response something other than 200? Does the response include an error message from the search engine?

Based on this line alone:

```
&msg("$chan",
"$logo(7@2$engine15)12 Total:4 (".scalar(@total).")12 Clean:4 (".scalar(@clean).")");
```

I also conclude that you're not using `use strict` and `use warnings`. [Do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)

Comment: no didn't give me results for google and yahoo engine for other i get some results but didn't much, yes response include an error message the search engine

Comment: @Doni Anugerah - don't keep us in suspense. What is the error message?

Comment: Thanks, but I have try get same problem could you check the script i upload could you help bro?