# Signal SIGSTOP received, but no signal handler set in perl script

Tags: multithreading, perl, signals

I have the following code in my perl script which somehow doesn't seem to work:

```
my $thr;

sub start__server_thread()
{
        $thr = threads->create(\&iperf_start_server, $_[0], $_[1], $_[2]);
        print("Value of thread is $thr\n");
        &START_SERVER_RESPONSE($controller_ip, $controller_port, "success", 2345, $_[1]);
}

sub iperf_start_server()
{
# Do some stuff here and then handle the signal
$SIG{'SIGSTOP'} = sub {
        print("Stop signal received\n");
        $thr->exit();
        $flag = 1;
        };
}

sub stop_server()
{
        my ($dat,$filelog,$result);
        $thr->kill('STOP');
        $flag = 1;
        sleep(10);
        $thr->exit(1);
}
```

When from some other context stop_server() is called, it tries to send the SIGSTOP signal to the thread. It is at this point that the execution stops and I get the error "Signal SIGSTOP received, but no  signal handler set in perl script. Where have i gone wrong?

Comment: [Don't use prototypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad) -- declare Perl subs as `sub name { ... }` not `sub name() { ... }`.

Comment: What platform are you running this on? I think your problem is that you cannot trap the `STOP` or `KILL` signals.

Comment: I am trying the above code on Linux

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting `$SIG{STOP}`, not `$SIG{SIGSTOP}`.

If you `use warnings`, you would have been alerted to this error. And if you `use diagnostics`, you would get some practical advice on what caused the error and how to fix it.

Comment: Doesn't help if I add use warnings and use diagnostics