# Passing array, scalar and hash to subroutine in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hashmap

What's the best way to send multiple arrays, variables, hashes to a subroutine?

Simple form, works.

```
my $msg = &getMsg(1,2,3);
print $msg;

sub getMsg {
    my($a, $b, $c) = @_;
}
```

I am having difficulty with this version and am not sure how to send the data safely to the subroutine without using a global which is not what I want to do.

```
my @array = ('a','b','c');
my $str = "Hello";
my %hash = (
    'a' => ['100','nuts'],
    'b' => ['200','bolts'],
    'c' => ['300','screws'],
);

my $msg = getMsg(@array, $str, %hash);
print $msg;

sub getMsg {
    my (@a, $s, %h) = @_;
    my $MSG;
    foreach my $x (@a) {
        $MSG .= "\n$str, $x your hash value = $h{$x}[0] $h{$x}[1]";
    }
    return $MSG
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use references:

```
getMsg(\@array, \%hash, $scalar);

sub getMsg {
    my ($aref, $href, $foo) = @_;
    for my $elem (@$aref) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that the assignment you tried:

```
my (@a, $s, %h) = @_;
```

Does not work, because `@a` -- being an array -- will slurp up the entire list, leaving `$s` and `%h` uninitialized.

Comment: Note that the passed hashref needs to be dereferenced when used in the sub `$MSG.= "\n$str, $x your hash value = $h->{$x}->[0] $h->{$x}->[1]"; `

Answer (score 6):

I prefer TLP's answer, but you can also use a prototype:

```
getMsg(@array, %hash, $scalar);

sub getMsg (\@\%$) {
    my ($aref, $href, $foo) = @_;
    for my $elem (@$aref) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The prototype `(\@\%$)` coerces the arguments to the subroutine call to a list reference, a hash reference, and a scalar *before* the arguments are flattened and loaded into `@_`. Inside the subroutine, you receive a list reference and a hash reference instead of an array and a hash.

Usually, though, [don't use prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad).