# Can I pass two variables through a subroutine and if can how to grab the passed variables?

Tags: perl

Below is the example of codes:

```
$test1 = "abc";
$test2 = "def";

function($test1,$test2);

sub function($){
    --What should I do here to get the `$test1` and `$test2`--
    --Is it possible?--
}
```

Expected Result:

Able to grab `$test1` and `$test2` inside the sub function by passing through the `function($test1,$test2)`.

Thanks for the comments ,teaching and answers.

Comment: `function($)` means the function only takes one argument, not two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the subroutine the arguments will be available in `@_`. You can retrieve them using [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html):

```
my $test1 = shift;
my $test2 = shift;
```

or by assigning `@_` to a list:

```
my ($test1, $test2) = @_;
```

or by directly accessing them (any changes will also be reflected outside):

```
print $_[0];
print $_[1];
```

e.g.

```
function($test1,$test2);

sub function {
    my ($test1, $test2) = @_;
    # Do something with the arguments.
}
```

Note I've removed the prototype from `function` as you [probably don't want it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad) and it was only allowing one argument.