# Subroutine arguments in perl

Tags: perl

I have been browsing a few of the perl modules where they have used `$$%`, `$$`, `$$$`, `@`, `$%`, `@..` and so on in the function arguments.

I understand that `$$` in the argument ensures that you have to pass 2 non-optional parameters and `$` for 1 non-optional parameter. Do the others have similar meaning as well?

Comment: [`perldoc perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: And search for "Prototypes".

Comment: @KeithThompson It is already permalinked in the link I provided

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are function prototypes. Everything you need to know about prototypes is in [`perlsub`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsub#Prototypes).

Before you read it a second time, read all of the answers in [Why are Perl 5's function prototypes bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad) and [Far More Than Everything You've Ever Wanted to Know about Prototypes in Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861966) and see if it disabuses you of the notion to use prototypes.

Comment: @user2189668: What you should take away from this is a decision to avoid subroutine prototypes in your own code