# Error while creating an instance by using $self in a perl script

Tags: perl, attributes, self, shift

I try to create an object inside my perl Script. Therefore I have a constructor

```
new(;@)
{
     my $class = shift;
     my $self = {};
     bless $self, $class;
     $self->_init(@_);
     return $self;
}
```

And my `_init(;@)` Function, to initialise the object

```
my $self = shift;
if( @_ )
{
    my %extra = @_;
    @$self{keys %extra} = values %extra;
}
return;
```

Am I using this two functions the wrong way? I am starting every other sub with the two lines

```
my $self = shift;
croak "instance method called for class" unless ref $self;
```

But I get only `syntax` / `String found where operator expected` errors in return for every single time I am using it.

Therefore my Question: Am I using the two functions the right way? I always thought I only need to initialise `$self` once, like I did, and can point everything I want to it for the rest of the Script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`croak` is not loaded by default. You must `use Carp` in the package to be able to use it (see [Carp](http://p3rl.org/Carp)).

BTW, prototypes are ignored with method calls. Don't use them. [Don't use them for functions, either.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/297034/1030675)

You might use something like [Class::Declare::Attributes](http://p3rl.org/Class::Declare::Attributes) to save some typing:

```
sub new :class {
    ...
}
```