# clean way to pass argument to perl subroutine to child routine as they are without storing to variable first?

Tags: perl

I want to pass the arguments of my routine to a subroutine as they are, possibly while adding a new argument.  To give an example imagine something like this

```
sub log($$$){
   my ($message, $log_location, $log_level) = @_;
   #logs message
}

sub log_debug($$){
   my ($message, $log_location) = @_;
   log($message, $log_location, DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL);
}
```

That syntax works fine above, but requires my saving the @_ to intermediate variables to do it.  I'm wondering if there is a simple clean syntax for doing so without using the intermediate variables.  Something like

```
log(@_, DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL);
```

which gets an error about my "not having enough variables", but I think would otherwise work.  Can this be done easily without warning?

Comment: Yeah, [don't use prototypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad). ;-)

Comment: or you can use `log($_[0], $_[1], DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to copy the elements of `@_`. You could use them directly as follows:

```
sub log_debug($$) {
    log($_[0], $_[1], DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL);
}
```

Prefixing the call with `&` causes the prototype to be ignored, so you could also use the following:

```
sub log_debug($$) {
    &log(@_, DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL);
}
```

If you eliminate the arguments (including `()`), the callee will use the parent's `@_` instead of creating a new one. This following is slightly more efficient than the previous solution:

```
sub log_debug($$) {
    push @_, DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL;
    &log;
}
```

Finally, if `log` obtains a stack trace, you might want to remove `log_debug` from the trace. This is slightly less efficient.

```
sub log_debug($$) {
    push @_, DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL;
    goto &log;
}
```

Note that none of four solutions I posted make a copy of the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just skip the [prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes)

```
sub log {
   my ($message, $log_location, $log_level) = @_;
   #logs message
}

sub log_debug {
   log(@_, DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip prototype checking by calling your subroutine with an `&`:

```
&log(@_, DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL);
```

According to [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

> Not only does the `&` form make the argument list optional, it also
>   disables any prototype checking on arguments you do provide. This is
>   partly for historical reasons, and partly for having a convenient way
>   to cheat if you know what you're doing.