# Step by step of trimming white-space

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to both perl and using regex. I need to remove the white space from a string.

I found an example but its pretty opaque to me. Is this an accurate description of whats happening?

```
sub trim($)
{
  my $string = shift;
  $string =~ s/^\s+//;
  # =~         : regex on variable string
  # s/         : replace match with value
  # ^\s+       : one or more white space characters at beginning
  # //         : no characters

  $string =~ s/\s+$//;
  #  =~        : regex on variable $string
  # s/         : replace match with value
  # \s+$       : one or more white space characters until end of line
  # //         : no characters
  return $string;
}
```

Comment: `=~` and `s///` are documented in perlop [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) and [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2f_PATTERN_%2f_REPLACEMENT_%2fmsixpodualngcer). If you have perldoc installed on your system, you can even view the documentation locally by running `perldoc perlop`. [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) are good resources for understanding regular expressions.

Comment: Also, you should generally [avoid prototypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad) in your own code. Instead of `sub trim($) { ... }` do `sub trim { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, as answered by [sidyll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557306/sidyll). All your comments are accurate. Since these are basics you are asking, I would like to add a little.

You can do both in one expression, `s/^\s+|\s+$//g` (there are slight efficiency considerations).
Note that now you need `/g` ("global") modifier so that *all* `\s+` are found. Otherwise the engine stops after it finds `^\s+` (if there are any) and you are left with trailing space (if any).

You can use spaces in your regex, for readability, by using `/x` modifier. In this case it isn't much but with more complex ones it can help a lot.

```
$string =~ s% ^\s+ | \s+$ %%gx;
```

You may use different delimiters -- as long as you don't use that inside the regex. I use `%` above to avoid the editor coloring everything red (I find `%` not very readable in fact, but I need `|` inside). This is sometimes very useful, for example when your regex has a lot of `/`.  Then you can use a different delimiter so you don't have to escape them.

---

Complete resources are given by [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) in the comment.

I've seen people praise this a lot: [regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD6mV0/1), where you can type in a regex and see how it works.

Comment: so the whole thing could be: `$string =~ s/ ^\s+ | \s*$ //x;` ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is.

Nothing else to say, actually.

Comment: I wonder if this is really an answer, but what is there else to say :)