# Perl Subroutine Declaration Unexpected Symbols

Tags: perl, syntax, declaration, function-declaration

I have been looking at some Perl code that has some subroutine declarations that make no sense to me.  They appear as:

```
foo($$$$;$);
foo(\$\$\$);
```

What do the symbols ";" and "\" do or mean in these declarations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're ["prototypes"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) - but Perl prototypes aren't like those in other languages, and probably shouldn't be used.

The `$` denotes a scalar argument to the function. `;$` denotes an optional additional scalar argument. And `\$` denotes a reference argument.

See also: [Why are Perl 5's function prototypes bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad)

Comment: [Obligatory "why prototypes are bad" link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad)

Comment: Pilfered and edited into the answer.