# How to get the index of the last digit in a string in Perl?

Tags: perl

In Perl, how do you find the index of the last digit in a string?

Example: `Hello123xyz` index of last digit is `7`

Answer (score 5):

A RE to match the last digit in the string and the [`@-` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/variables/@-) to get the index of the start of the match:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;

sub last_digit_index($) {
    if ($_[0] =~ /\d\D*\z/) {
        return $-[0];
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

say last_digit_index("Hello123xyz"); # 7
```

Comment: Nice, (++) , what is `($)` please?

Comment: @GillesQuénot A prototype. See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Prototypes for details.

Comment: See also [Why are Perl 5's function prototypes bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad)

Comment: And I'm not sure why you'd go to all the effort of writing your own version of [`index()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index).

Comment: @DaveCross My own version of index? Huh? This does something pretty different from that function.

Comment: Perl *could* use a version of `index` that searches right to left for the last match. And then use it ten times for all 10 digits and take their maximum... might be useful for some other task though, but not this.

Comment: The right to left version of `index` is `rindex`

Comment: Of course it is. Silly me, expecting it to be mentioned in the documentation for `index`. Still useless here as already noted.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Typo in my comment (twice actually, because it's in the link too!)

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably use the [`pos`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos) function here. Match with `/g` and the Perl remembers where the match left off. The next global match on that string will start where the last match left off, so isolate this in a sub or block to avoid weird effects on subsequent matches on the same variable.

Since the position counts from 0, the next position will be one greater than the 1-based position of the final digit. You decide if you want to subtract 1 or not:

```
use v5.10;

say last_digit_pos('Hello123xyz');

sub last_digit_pos {
    my( $string ) = @_;
    $string =~ m/^.*\d/sg;
    return pos($string);  # 6
    }
```

And, if the string doesn't match, `pos` doesn't return a defined value.

Answer (score 3):

Can also leverage [List::MoreUtils::last_index](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#last_index-BLOCK-LIST)

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(last_index);

my $last_digit_index = last_index { /[0-9]/ } split '', $string;
```

I find this simple: break the string into a list of characters with a typical use of `split`, and use a library to find the last one which is a digit, via a trivial regex.

Note that this is "expensive" as it creates a scalar for each character and runs regex multiple times. So if efficiency matters -- if this is done on an absolutely gigantic string, or many many many times on smaller strings -- then better seek other approaches, or at least benchmark before deciding.

Comment: This is a lot more expensive as it involves creating many scalars, multiple sub calls and multiple regex evaluations.

Comment: @ikegami "_expensive_" -- well, yes, fully agree.  But I guess that that won't matter and wanted to draw attention to a way that doesn't involve a lot more complex regex manipulations/properties but is rather simple (conceptually), in comparison.  Thanks for bringing it up though, I should've stated that.  Adding a comment...